# How to parse XML from table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have data in XML in column in table

```
SELECT ObjectXML
FROM DispOps_Events
```

```
[ObjectXML] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
```

[image]

A sample of the XML data:

```
    <Document>
       <DocumentId>3352597</DocumentId>
       <DocumentFullPath>xxx</DocumentFullPath>
       <Category>xxx</Category>
       <ClientId>xxx</ClientId>
       <ApplicationNumber>xxx</ApplicationNumber>
       <ContractNumber>xxx</ContractNumber>
       <Created>xxx</Created>
       <Creator>xxx</Creator>
    </Document>
```

And I need get data from `DocumentId>XXXX/DocumentId>` and insert into `#tmpTable`.

So 1. I cast `varchar(max)` to `xml`

```
select CAST(ObjectXML as XML) as fileXML
    INTO #tmpXML
FROM DispOps_Events T WHERE MetastormMapName = 'DocumentsMap'
```

I tried

```
    select
    m.c.value('@DocumentId', 'varchar(max)') as DocumentId
    --into #tmpTable
from #tmpXML as s
    outer apply s.fileXML.nodes('Document/DocumentId') as m(c)
```

Error:

> null data in the table

[image]

Comment: Well, as the error message suggests, `nodes`, `query` and `value` only work on XML data types. Have you tried casting your `nvarchar(max)` to `xml`?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need #temp tables to do this, you can just cast the `nvarchar(max)` data to the `xml` data type in a single query, e.g.:

```sql
/*
 * Setup test data...
 */
drop table if exists dbo.DispOps_Events;
create table dbo.DispOps_Events (
    ID int not null identity(1,1),
    ObjectXML nvarchar(max)
);

insert dbo.DispOps_Events (ObjectXML) values
    (N'<Document><DocumentId>2554742</DocumentId><!--...--></Document>'),
    (N'<Document><DocumentId>2576868</DocumentId><!--...--></Document>'),
    (N'<Document><DocumentId>2576869</DocumentId><!--...--></Document>'),
    (N'<Document><DocumentId>2576870</DocumentId><!--...--></Document>');

/*
 * Query XML...
 */
select  ID, [DocumentId] = Document.DocumentId.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
from dbo.DispOps_Events
cross apply ( select try_cast(ObjectXML as xml) ) Transformers(RoolyTroolyXml)
cross apply RoolyTroolyXml.nodes('/Document/DocumentId') as Document(DocumentId);
```

| ID | DocumentId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2554742 |
| 2 | 2576868 |
| 3 | 2576869 |
| 4 | 2576870 |